# Gradle exception while building GraniteDS project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, graniteds

Good day, everyone.
I'm trying to build GraniteDS project locally: https://github.com/graniteds/graniteds
but when I try to build it I'm facing:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'graniteds-master'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.FileSystems
        at org.gradlefx.conventions.GradleFxConvention.class$(GradleFxConvention.groovy)
        at org.gradlefx.conventions.GradleFxConvention.$get$$class$org$gradle$internal$nativeplatform$filesystem$FileSystems(GradleFxConvention.groovy)
```

I can find this class: org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.FileSystems
in GRADLE_HOME/lib/gradle-native-2.4.jar

Does anyone know why that can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have installed gradle on your machine and are building using the `gradle` command. The preferred way of using gradle is not to install it on your machine explicitly, and instead include the [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) in your source which lazily downloads a specific gradle version.

I note that the project has included a gradle wrapper (`gradlew.bat`) and I'm guessing that the version is different from that installed in `GRADLE_HOME` on your machine.

Try using the supplied gradle wrapper instead which just means typing `gradlew` instead of `gradle`.

Comment: thank you, Lance! that helped me a lot. You were right in all points. First time playing with Gradle.

Comment: one more question, if you don't mind. Is there a possibility to build exact modules, not all of them?